Why was this +10 answer deleted by a moderator (some time ago)?
I just saw that this answer of mine was deleted 4 months ago: Is it defensible to claim that religion is a personal relationship with God and therefore contains no claims?
In that answer, I try to break down the various aspects of religious beliefs when viewed as a relationship, and which parts of it would and wouldn't constitute claims, and which parts of that we'd expect evidence for.
It has a score of 10 (+11/-1), making it the second-most upvoted answer on that thread, and it's the only answer on that thread that was deleted by a moderator.
Someone left a comment (with no upvotes) saying "This answer could be improved with editing, by making it more polished, refined, structured, and succinct", although the answer is separated into 3 sections with headings, and contains bullet points and a numbered list. But even if someone considers it unpolished, it doesn't seem reasonable or appropriate for this alone to be sufficient to warrant (silent) mod deletion (especially given the 11 people who thought the answer was useful).
So why was it deleted?

To speculate a bit:
I can accept that people might downvote an answer that could be said to be critical of religion, or merely because it's written from an atheist/skeptic perspective, even if it answers the question that was asked.
But I would hope that mods wouldn't be deleting questions for that reason. Unless the post is unnecessarily inflammatory, of course, which I don't think I was being, but that's best for others to judge. I might've gotten mildly spicy in the last paragraph, where I said, for example, "you probably also shouldn't look too much into other religions, that may also meet that standard", but if that's crossing the line... really? But also, I could easily rephrase that to be more neutral (although, if that's the problem, I'd hope that a user with 100s of answers and plenty of reputation would at least be made aware that this is a problem, and have the opportunity to fix their answer, rather than having it just be silently deleted).

The flag said "It should be edited to improve the clarity, organization and succinctness.", so I don't know why it was deleted. I'll contact my fellow mod for review.

I find your (physicalist) answers annoying. But I like being annoyed  ie I dont much like the excessive/wanton deletes that keep happening. As I've said elsewhere. And... etc

Deleted in error - sincere apologies. Now re-opened. Geoffrey Thomas.

Question deleted in error - sincere apologies. It's now re-opened. Geoffrey Thomas

@GeoffreyThomas Sorry, I'm not quite following. I'm asking about a deleted answer, not a closed/deleted question, and it still seems to be deleted.

@GeoffreyThomas can you share what makes you accidentally delete it? It would help improve the UX of the site

I didn't accidentally delete - I made a misjudgement about the quality of the answer.  We all make mistakes and I have rectified and apologised without qualification for mine. I am deeply sorry about the whole episode.

The answer has been undeleted. (Thanks).

Posting this as an answer so I can "accept" an answer to indicate that this is resolved. (Although I need to wait a few hours before I can accept my own answer)

How can a moderator selectively, unprompted, well after the fact, delete an answer that he personally thought was low quality (and can physically see the 10 upvotes) then right after use “we all make mistakes” as an excuse only after being called out?
Yes, we all make mistakes, but this seems like the kind of thing that is very obviously not fit for a moderator. It’s no wonder this site is clunky.

Because we all make mistakes, and moderators are volunteers. Patience with your fellow human is the best strategy in this situation.
